Determine if factorial of exponent is bigger than exponent of factorial
For natural values $a$, $b$ determine if $(a^b)! > a^{b!}$.
My thoughts : since logarithm is strictly monotonic $a > b \iff \ln(a) > \ln(b)$, let's consider $\ln(a^b)! - \ln(a^{b!})$. Using Stirling's approximation, we have $(a^b\times b\ln(b) - a^b) - b!\ln(a)$. Comparing logarithms of values once again, $\ln(a^b\times b\ln(b) - a^b) - \ln(b!\ln(a)) = (b\ln(a) + \ln(b\ln(a) - 1)) - (b(\ln(b) - 1) + \ln(ln(a)))$. Hence we need to check if $b\ln(a) + \ln(b\ln(a) - 1) > b(\ln(b) - 1) + \ln(\ln(a))$.

On the LHS there are $a^b$ numbers $\le a^b$, therefore $LHS\le (a^b)^{a^b}=a^{ba^b}$. For all $a$, eventually $b!> ba^b$, therefore for all $a>1$ eventually $LHS< RHS$

@SassatelliGiulio, however wolfram says that, for example a = 2 and b = 4123, LHS>RHS

LHS < RHS .

@SassatelliGiulio, sorry, messed up with order, but still link

@vitalyvolovyk Unsurprisingly so. As I said, for all $a>1$, eventually $(a^b)!<a^{b!}$, id est $$[\forall a>1,\exists N,\forall b\ge N, (a^b)!<a^{b!}]$$
